# fpca "incorrect number of subscripts on matrix"

Tags: r

I cannot understand where is the error in this simple command...

```
var<-("a","b","c","d")
expliquer<-("a")
explicative<-("b", "c", "d")
fpca(data=dataset, y=expliquer, x=explicative, partial="No")
```

The result is

> "Error in mat[, i + 1] <- datafile[, c(x[i])] : 
>         incorrect number of subscripts on matrix"

I tried modifying the dataset (is a normal numeric dataset...nothing weird such as NA or empty cells...)